# User settings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to save `Name` `Value` pair in settings dynamically. I can see the new saved values dynamically. But, when I access the settings page from the property window , it shows the same old value. Here is the code :

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.Name = textBox1.Text;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Age = textBox2.Text;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: When you say Property Window, are you referring to the one inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. The one which we get when we right click on the          Solution->Properties->Settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are testing your application with Visual Studio, your problem happens because, when you are changing the setting of your application you aren't changing the original setting file. When Visual Studio starts running an application, it creates a folder inside the directory where your code is named "obj/Debug" or "obj/Release" and copies all your DLLs and resources into that folders, including settings files.

This means that changes to settings will be reflected in your "obj/Debug/yourappname.exe.config" and not in the original file. If you open this file, for example, with a text editor you'll see the contents have changed. Remember that every time you recompile your application in Visual Studio and start running this file will be replaced by the original, losing your new settings.

You can manually run your .exe application inside that folder and validate if your settings have persisted.

Comment: So, you the settings are not reflected in the original file . But are stored in the Debug directory inside settings.exe

Comment: The appname.exe.config in the \bin\Debug directory still contains the default values for user app settings.  This is the result of compiling app.config to the output folder.  The persisted run time settings will be saved in a file named user.config.  User.config can be found under the Windows user profile.  For example, on Windows7, the default path is C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<company>\<hash of app name>\<version>\user.config.  The yourapp.exe.config in \bin\Debug folder will always contain the default values as you would want to deploy your app with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

After compile the settings file gets deployed into a yourapplication.exe.config file. This is the file you are changing (/Debug/app.exe.config). If you want to see changes in your "property window" you have to manually open the .settings file and edit the xml.

Note: after changing the .config file the changes are persistent .. but only until you compile your application again.

Answer (score 1):

The solution->Properties->Settings is where you set the default values.  User settings can be changed at run-time, and will persist with your application, but they are not written back to your visual studio project.

In your example, if you run the program again on subsequent times (* not by hitting debug / rebuild in visual studio), your settings that are saved in your snippet will have been persisted.

Imagine that your program has been deployed on user's pc's - there shouldn't be a mechanism for that to change your visual studio project settings file.